# Does shouldComponentUpdate block getDerivedStateFromProps?

Tags: reactjs

I am updating a legacy component which uses:

1. `shouldComponentUpdate()` to avoid an expensive state re-computation
2. `componentWillUpdate()` to do the re-computation and render if **1** passes

The [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) say

> if `shouldComponentUpdate()` returns `false`, then
>   `UNSAFE_componentWillUpdate()`, `render()`, and `componentDidUpdate()` will not be invoked`

But `getDerivedStateFromProps()` is not mentioned. I want to use this to replace the deprecated `componentWillUpdate()`.

My question is: does `shouldComponentUpdate()` block the invocation of `getDerivedStateFromProps()` in the same way as it did for `componentWillUpdate()`?

NB: I know about looking at memoization as another solution.

Comment: `getDerivedStateFromProps()` is being called before `shouldComponentUpdate()`. Try adding some `console.log()` in each lifecycle method to see

Answer (score 0):

When the passed props change `getDerivedStateFromProps()` function is called and then `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

However if state changes only the `shouldComponentUpdate()` lifecycle function is triggered.

You can check the component lifecycle diagram [here](https://grokonez.com/frontend/react/react-component-lifecycle-methods-from-v16-3-react-lifecycle-example) for more help

Comment: getDerivedStateFromProps also run if state changes.